# Unacceptable value in associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I set value in associative array in 2D array in JavaScript. I used a following source code:

```js
var properties = {
  "isBold": false,
  "isItalic": false,
  "isUnderline": false
};

// Creation of 2D array, 6x6
var listOfProperties = new Array(6);
for (var i = 0; i < listOfProperties.length; i++) {
  listOfProperties[i] = new Array(6);
}

// Population of listOfProperties with properties
for (var row = 0; row < listOfProperties.length; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < listOfProperties.length; col++) {
    listOfProperties[row][col] = properties;
  }
}

var property = listOfProperties[2][2];
property.isBold = true; // I would like to populate property isBold
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);

var property = listOfProperties[0][0];
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);
```

I created 2D array which I populated with *properties* (associative array, all values are false). Then I set a *true* for *isBold* for *listOfProperties[2][2]**.

But why *isBold* in *listOfProperties[0][0]* includes *true* instead *false*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the 2D array of copies of the object, not the reference:

```js
var properties = {
  "isBold": false,
  "isItalic": false,
  "isUnderline": false
};

// Creation of 2D array, 6x6
var listOfProperties = new Array(6);
for (var i = 0; i < listOfProperties.length; i++) {
  listOfProperties[i] = new Array(6);
}

// Population of listOfProperties with properties
for (var row = 0; row < listOfProperties.length; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < listOfProperties.length; col++) {
    listOfProperties[row][col] = Object.assign({}, properties);
  }
}

var property = listOfProperties[1][1];
property.isBold = true; // I would like to populate property isBold
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);

var property = listOfProperties[0][0];
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);
```

For more details, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).